# Powershell command for importing Certificates to the "UNTRUSTED CERTIFICATES\CERTIFICATES" location

Tags: powershell

The command I'm using that is working perfectly for the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities\Certificates is:

$file = (Get-Childitem -Path "D:/Root CA 2.cer")

$file = Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\Root

When it comes to the 6 different certs that need to be imported to the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" this command works perfectly.  Root CA 2, 3, 4, 5, and the two different ECA Root's 2 and 4 all are placed in their location.  However, when it comes to the CCEB Interoperability cert, this command also places it in the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".  The CCEB Cert is supposed to be located in the "Untrusted Certificates" location.  What confuses me most is that when you use the MMC console and right click import and choose this file, it automatically knows that it's supposed to be in the "Untrusted" location.  I thought that the Powershell command would produce the same result, but it doesn't.  It keeps placing it in the wrong location.  I'm brand new to Powershell and can't find any discussion on this topic.  Please help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell can use `cert:\` paths to browse the certificate store like a file system. Check out the [about_Certificate_provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/about/about_certificate_provider) page for more details. Each cert store's name is a little different from what you see in the MMC though.

`cert:\LocalMachine\Root` is the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" store, so **any** certificates you import are placed there when you specify `-CertStoreLocation` that way

"Untrusted Certificates" is named **Disallowed**, so you can import like so:

```sh
Get-Item "D:\folder\BadCerts.sst" | 
  Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\Disallowed"
```

Powershell can't easily display the certificate trust list (CTL) in the untrusted certs store, but can import just fine

Comment: That makes complete sense.  It worked perfectly.  I knew I was missing something that is completely obvious after being steered down the correct path. Im in the process of automating a build that I did and experiencing PowerShell for the first time.

Comment: What about for certutil in command prompt? Is the Store name the same? "disallowed"

Comment: @SprJD7903 The name is the same. For example, you can use `certutil -store disallowed` to dump the current list of untrusted certificates (and `certutil -user -store disallowed` for the current user if they have any)